# JDA Send DM to pinged roles

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

```
package com.commands;

import com.company.Main;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Role;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class MassDM extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(@NotNull GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        super.onGuildMessageReceived(event);
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.BOT_PREFIX+"massdm")){
            Role role = event.getMessage().getMentionedRoles().get(0);
            for(Member member: event.getGuild().getMembersWithRoles(role)){
                System.out.println(member);
                    try{
                        System.out.println(member.toString());
                        member.getUser().openPrivateChannel()
                                .flatMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage("Hello sir"))
                                .queue();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                    }



            }
        }


    }
}
```

Hello, So I am writing a discord bot to dm people with a specific role. In my code, however, didn't work, what did i miss? I am using JDA 4.3

Comment: What do you mean with `didn't work`? What about using a debugger?

Comment: I mean, I printed the part where i am doing foreach loop but it didn't even print out anything

Comment: Did you enable the privileged intent `GUILD_MEMBERS` and member caching?

Comment: I didn't, can you show me some examples?

Comment: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy

Answer (score 0):

First of all i raccomend to remove @Override and that super.

---

Try by setting that role manually

```
Role role = event.getGuild().getRoleById(roleid);
```

---

...then i will try changing to

```
user.openPrivateChannel().queue(privateChannel -> {
 //send message here
}
```

---

Remember that Discord will rate limit your bot if it sends too many messages in a short period of time even if it's not verified.

> All bots can make up to 50 requests per second to our API.